# Netcat like listening program in delphi does not send back commands

Tags: sockets, delphi, winsock, remote-access, netcat

I have a delphi program that listens to port 8080 using winsock
here is the code so far:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  WinSock;

var
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  ServerSocket,ClientSocket: TSocket;
  ServerAddr, ClientAddr: TSockAddr;
  ClientAddrSize,Status,ret: Integer;
  Buffer1,buffer2: array[0..1024] of Char;

begin
  writeln('started..');
  WSAStartup($0101,WSAData);
  ServerSocket:=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
  ServerAddr.sin_family:=AF_INET;
  ServerAddr.sin_port:=htons(8080);
  ServerAddr.sin_addr.S_addr:=INADDR_ANY;
  bind(ServerSocket,ServerAddr,SizeOf(ServerAddr));
  listen(ServerSocket,10);
  ClientAddrSize:=SizeOf(ClientAddr);
  ClientSocket:=accept(ServerSocket,@ClientAddr,@ClientAddrSize);
  if ClientSocket <>  INVALID_SOCKET then
  begin
  while True do
   begin
    ret:=recv(ClientSocket,Buffer2,SizeOf(Buffer2),0);
    Writeln(Buffer2);
    Readln(Input, Buffer1);
    ret:=send(ClientSocket,Buffer1,SizeOf(Buffer1),0);
   end;
  end;

end.
```

As you can see from the screenshot here:
[image]

I open netcat and connect to my program using "nc 127.0.0.1 8080 -e cmd.exe"
to open a remote command shell.

My program gets the first lines that you normally see when you open a command prompt but later i can't execute commands like "dir", even though I send the command after

```
Readln(Input, Buffer1);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: As you can see, the "dir" command is written below the "C:\>"
i need to do it like netcat, perhaps i need to create a pipe for the command.

Comment: Not sure how `netcat` works but, are you sure you are sending the line termination characters for each command?

Comment: hm, you have a vaild point, i'll make a test.

Comment: that was it, if i append the characters #13#10 at the end of each Buffer1 that i send the command executes.

Comment: Nice, put it as an answer so that anyone can quickly see the solution and I'll upvote it. :-)

Comment: I will when i'll finish it, i spotted some terrible mistakes, i don't clear the buffer1, so when i send "dir" for the second time, the buffer1 becomes "dirdir" :P The same goes for buffer2 (response)

Comment: Also, i got a more weird problem, for some reason the command executes only if i press enter two times :P

Comment: Maybe one enter for `netcat` and the second one for the command sent to `cmd`?

Comment: I don't know, i posted an answer with the full code so you can test it if you want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not absolutely correct so far, because for some reason it echoes back the first command and for the rest it needs two enters to execute.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  WinSock,
  uSockFunc in 'uSockFunc.pas';

var
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  ServerSocket,ClientSocket: TSocket;
  ServerAddr, ClientAddr: TSockAddr;
  ClientAddrSize: Integer;
  Buffer1, buffer2 : string;

begin
  writeln('started..');
  WSAStartup($101,WSAData);
  ServerSocket:=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
  ServerAddr.sin_family:=AF_INET;
  ServerAddr.sin_port:=htons(8080);
  ServerAddr.sin_addr.S_addr:=INADDR_ANY;
  bind(ServerSocket,ServerAddr,SizeOf(ServerAddr));
  listen(ServerSocket,10);
  ClientAddrSize:=SizeOf(ClientAddr);
  ClientSocket:=accept(ServerSocket,@ClientAddr,@ClientAddrSize);
  if ClientSocket <>  INVALID_SOCKET then
  begin
  while True do
   begin

    Buffer2 := RecvLn(ClientSocket, #$A);
    Writeln(Buffer2);
    Buffer2 := '';

    Readln(Input, Buffer1);
    SendString(ClientSocket, Buffer1 + #13#10);
    Buffer1 := '';

   end;
  end;

end.
```

I also used this unit which is not mine for the "SendString" and "RecvLn" function:

```
unit uSockFunc;

interface
uses windows, winsock;
const
EOL = #13#10;
function Connect(address : String;  port : Integer) : Integer;
procedure Disconnect(sinsock : TSocket);
function SendBuf(s : TSocket; var Buffer; Len : Integer) : Integer;
function SendString(s : TSocket; str : String) : Integer;
function RecvLn(s : TSocket; Delim: String = EOL): String;
function RecvLen(s : TSocket) : Integer;
function RecvBuf(s : TSocket; var Buffer; Len : Integer) : Integer;
implementation

function Connect(address : String;  port : Integer) : Integer;
var
  sinsock           : TSocket;
  SockAddrIn        : TSockAddrIn;
  hostent           : PHostEnt;
begin
  sinsock := Winsock.socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  SockAddrIn.sin_family := AF_INET;
  SockAddrIn.sin_port := htons(Port);
  SockAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(pchar(address));
  if SockAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_NONE then
  begin
    HostEnt := gethostbyname(pchar(Address));
    if HostEnt = nil then
    begin
      result := SOCKET_ERROR;
      Exit;
    end;
    SockAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr := Longint(PLongint(HostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
  end;                           //CHANGE MADE
  if Winsock.Connect(sinSock, SockAddrIn, SizeOf(SockAddrIn)) = SOCKET_ERROR Then
    result := SOCKET_ERROR
  else
    result := sinsock;
end;

function SendBuf(s : TSocket; var Buffer; Len : Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := send(s, Buffer, Len, 0);
end;

function SendString(s : TSocket; str : String) : Integer;
begin
  result := SendBuf(s, str[1],Length(str));
end;

function RecvLn(s : TSocket; Delim: String = EOL): String;
const
  BUFFER_SIZE = 255;
var
  Buffer: String;
  I, L: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  I := 1;
  L := 1;
  SetLength(Buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  while (L <= Cardinal(Length(Delim))) do
  begin
    if recv(s, Buffer[I], 1, 0) < 1 then Exit;
      ///
    if Buffer[I] = Delim[L] then
      Inc(L)
    else
      L := 1;
    Inc(I);
    if I > BUFFER_SIZE then
    begin
      Result := Result + Buffer;
      I := 1;
    end;
  end;
    Result := Result + Copy(Buffer, 0, I - L);
end;

function RecvLen(s : TSocket) : Integer;
begin
  if ioctlsocket(s, FIONREAD, Longint(Result)) = SOCKET_ERROR then
  begin
    Result := SOCKET_ERROR;
  end;
end;

function RecvBuf(s : TSocket; var Buffer; Len : Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := recv(s, Buffer, Len, 0);
  if (Result = SOCKET_ERROR) and (WSAGetLastError = WSAEWOULDBLOCK) then
  begin
   Result := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure Disconnect(sinsock : TSocket);
begin
  closesocket(sinsock);
end;
end.
```